# GetCurrentMethod of Parent Object

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to get the current method of a parent object?

I can get the current method using “System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.ToString”. However I want a utility class that can capture the “GetCurrentMethod” that is executing my utility class (the parent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class:

```
Dim st As New StackTrace(True)
Console.WriteLine(st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod())
```

Or, even better, if you just need the parent method, use [StackFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws7f30w6.aspx):

```
Dim sf As New StackFrame(1, True)
Console.WriteLine(sf.GetMethod())
```